# Передача объектов LinkedHashMap в Intent

Tags: android, java, сериализация

Имеется объект класса `LnkedHashMap`, например:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> data = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
data.put("..", "...");
 ...
```

Мне необходимо передать его в объекте Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
i.putExtra("dataMap", data);
```

А затем получить его в классе, вызываемом Intent'ом:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> data = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) data.getSerializableExtra("dataMap");
```

Однако, последняя строчка вызывает ошибку при работе программы.
В чем может быть дело? Насколько я знаю, класс `LinkedHashMap` реализует интерфейс сериализации, так откуда такое?

Comment: [Проблема на SO][1], может поможет
 [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890346/serialize-deserialize-a-linkedhashmap-android-java

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что нужно сделать под "add an annotation to tell the compiler to "shut up" about the unchecked cast". Какого рода аннотацию? К слову, компилируется все нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что генерики это raw-type, которые нельзя небезопасно привести, отсюда вы должны:

1. Приводить тип к LinkedHashMap<?, ?>, а потом скопировать его в новую типизированую коллекцию.
2. Или Добавить аннотацию @SuppressWarnings("unchecked").